# App not compatible with device on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, screen-size

My app is only designed for handsets, not tablets. However, with the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
                android:name="com.xxx.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application

...
...
...
        <activity
            android:name=".ParseLogInUI.ParseLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <!-- For more options, see https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-login -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME"
                android:value="true"/>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".DealsFromOurSponsors.AlarmService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Geofences.UserTracker">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name=".Geofences.LocalDealsBroadcastReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".DealsFromOurSponsors.Alarm"/>



        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.xxx.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Almost all of my android users are telling me it's not compatible with their device, or that they can't find it on the google play store. Yet under the "eligible devices" in my developer console it says that those devices are supported (I have 7611 supported devices).

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Do you limit the listing to certain country only?

Comment: minsdk or sth like that in build gradle?

Comment: No, all countries. And the minsdk in the build gradle is 15, with a target of 22.

Comment: Did you find the issue? If so, can you please share it?

Answer (score 1):

Please specify your minimum sdk version and target sdk version, Google Play store direct reffer that both values from manifest file and then decide wheather application has been support to the particular device or not...

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" /
```

Here your appication can support only Above 14 Api versions,  if below 14 api version devices try to search on playstore then your app displayed on play store.. only visible for above 14 onwords  API Level

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you don't have all the densities. Just add the following lines:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <!-- normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Source http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: What is default compatible screen size list?