# Google Play console : 0 supported devices

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am struggling to find an answer to that. i read the Google docs about manifest filtering such as [manifest filtering](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) and i also found a few similar issues around the forum like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de) and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004768/app-not-compatible-with-device-on-google-play-store) but nothing works so far i see on my console that app is supported by 0 devices here is my AndroidMnifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="app.googledrive">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 <supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="my contacts backup"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

    >
```

my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.googledrive"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2.2.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])




compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `supports-screens`

Comment: what is your sdk versions in gradle file?

Comment: according to the documentation the screen support is mandatory is that so?

Comment: the weird thing is that now it shows 11,000+ supported devices. when i attempt to install on real devices with supported sdk it says not compatible

Comment: I've seen people mentioning this frequently during the past 2 weeks, it seems to be a bug with the new Play Console